# restoring data in a specific table

Tags: mysql

One of our tables has been maligned 
/*edit as per commented request
On doing an update to a specific column I accidentally neglected to specify for which row I wish to make this change and set the offending value for every row in the table.
*/end edit

but we have a very recent backup, however not so recent that other tables won't lose data if we do a total database restore.

I'm wondering what the procedure is (assuming there is one) of copying the contents of a given table from one database to another.

The largest problem is that I can't just drop the offending table and replace it as it has rows that are indexed by id into other tables. This won't be a problem if we just take the values from the identical rows in the back-up and bring them over (since the row ids wouldn't change).

Comment: Can you explain briefly what has gone wrong with the data in your current table? This will affect the ideal solution.

Comment: @rjdown, added an explanation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's unclear what exactly has gone wrong with your data. But I'm thinking maybe just a column or two has got messed up. As you said, you just want to copy over the data from the old table, based on the id column.

Assuming you've imported the backup database as "olddb" and the current one is named "newdb":

```
UPDATE newdb.yourtable newtable, olddb.yourtable oldtable
SET newtable.somecolumn = oldtable.somecolumn
WHERE newtable.id = oldtable.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Use mysqldatadump for that particular table, and then feed that into the other database.

You can edit the dump file prior to redaing it in to the target table.

See: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/9306/how-do-you-mysqldump-specific-tables

Comment: mysqldump creates insert statements. I need update statements as the rows in the maligned table are already there, they just need to be reset to their previous contents. When you say "edit the dump file" - not including altering each insert into an update which would be an impossible task considering the data quantity) is there some other way to achieve this?

Comment: Could you write a script to replace the inserts with a update? Something like sed